# More efficient way to remove from an object attributes present in a group of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm manipulating some javascript objects and I want to know if is there a more efficient and easy way to process my data.
I already do that, but I'm a beginner in js.

I have four objects with this structure: basically there is an array of blocks and any object has a different number of blocks. In every block, in the features attribute, I have another array with some features.

Then I have another object, and I have to remove from this object (I call it structure) blocks and features that are not present in my four initial object.

This is a sample **product object**

```
[
  {
    "ID": 16293,
    "SortNo": "20",
    "FeatureGroup": {
      "ID": "148",
      "Name": {
        "Value": "Design",
        "Language": "IT"
      }
    },
    "Features": [
      {
        "Localized": 0,
        "ID": "155744521",
        "Type": "dropdown",
        "Value": "Round",
        "CategoryFeatureId": "85327",
        "CategoryFeatureGroupID": "16293",
        "SortNo": "155",
        "PresentationValue": "Rotondo",
        "RawValue": "Round",
        "LocalValue": [],
        "Description": "The external form",
        "Mandatory": "1",
        "Searchable": "0",
        "Feature": {
          "ID": "9397",
          "Sign": "",
          "Measure": {
            "ID": "29",
            "Sign": "",
            "Signs": {
              "ID": "",
              "_": "",
              "Language": "IT"
            }
          },
          "Name": {
            "Value": "Forma",
            "Language": "IT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Localized": 0,
        "ID": "155655523",
        "Type": "multi_dropdown",
        "Value": "White",
        "CategoryFeatureId": "85298",
        "CategoryFeatureGroupID": "16293",
        "SortNo": "90",
        "PresentationValue": "Bianco",
        "RawValue": "White",
        "LocalValue": [],
        "Description": "The colour of the housing",
        "Mandatory": "1",
        "Searchable": "1",
        "Feature": {
          "ID": "10059",
          "Sign": "",
          "Measure": {
            "ID": "29",
            "Sign": "",
            "Signs": {
              "ID": "",
              "_": "",
              "Language": "IT"
            }
          },
          "Name": {
            "Value": "Colore struttura",
            "Language": "IT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Localized": 0,
        "ID": "155655525",
        "Type": "multi_dropdown",
        "Value": "White",
        "CategoryFeatureId": "85301",
        "CategoryFeatureGroupID": "16293",
        "SortNo": "80",
        "PresentationValue": "Bianco",
        "RawValue": "White",
        "LocalValue": [],
        "Description": "The colour of the band",
        "Mandatory": "1",
        "Searchable": "1",
        "Feature": {
          "ID": "11025",
          "Sign": "",
          "Measure": {
            "ID": "29",
            "Sign": "",
            "Signs": {
              "ID": "",
              "_": "",
              "Language": "IT"
            }
          },
          "Name": {
            "Value": "Colore cinturino",
            "Language": "IT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Localized": 0,
        "ID": "219617494",
        "Type": "y_n",
        "Value": "Y",
        "CategoryFeatureId": "168947",
        "CategoryFeatureGroupID": "16293",
        "SortNo": "-6",
        "PresentationValue": "Sì",
        "RawValue": "Y",
        "LocalValue": [],
        "Description": "The product is protected from water",
        "Mandatory": "0",
        "Searchable": "0",
        "Feature": {
          "ID": "7509",
          "Sign": "",
          "Measure": {
            "ID": "26",
            "Sign": "",
            "Signs": {
              "ID": "",
              "_": "",
              "Language": "IT"
            }
          },
          "Name": {
            "Value": "Resistente all'acqua",
            "Language": "IT"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": 34567,
    "SortNo": "20",
    "FeatureGroup": {
      "ID": "184",
      "Name": {
        "Value": "Prestazione",
        "Language": "IT"
      }
    },
    "Features": [
      {
        "Localized": 0,
        "ID": "155744528",
        "Type": "y_n",
        "Value": "N",
        "CategoryFeatureId": "94697",
        "CategoryFeatureGroupID": "34567",
        "SortNo": "800",
        "PresentationValue": "No",
        "RawValue": "N",
        "LocalValue": [],
        "Description": "La Frequenza modulare radio produce la miglior recezione di qualsiasi canale radio. Quando viene usato un auricolare, produce un effetto di suono da stereo r",
        "Mandatory": "1",
        "Searchable": "0",
        "Feature": {
          "ID": "2172",
          "Sign": "",
          "Measure": {
            "ID": "26",
            "Sign": "",
            "Signs": {
              "ID": "",
              "_": "",
              "Language": "IT"
            }
          },
          "Name": {
            "Value": "Radio FM",
            "Language": "IT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Localized": 0,
        "ID": "155744530",
        "Type": "multi_dropdown",
        "Value": "Not supported",
        "CategoryFeatureId": "85357",
        "CategoryFeatureGroupID": "34567",
        "SortNo": "500",
        "PresentationValue": "Non supportato",
        "RawValue": "Not supported",
        "LocalValue": [],
        "Description": "Types of memory cards which can be used with this product.",
        "Mandatory": "1",
        "Searchable": "0",
        "Feature": {
          "ID": "730",
          "Sign": "",
          "Measure": {
            "ID": "29",
            "Sign": "",
            "Signs": {
              "ID": "",
              "_": "",
              "Language": "IT"
            }
          },
          "Name": {
            "Value": "Tipi schede di memoria",
            "Language": "IT"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here i loop my initial objects (this.compare_products) to extract, in two arrays (featureGroupIds - featureIds) the ID of my block and the CategoryFeatureId

```
    let featureGroupIds = []
    let featureIds = []

    this.compare_products.forEach((object) => {
      featureGroupIds = featureGroupIds.concat(FeaturesGroups.map(o => o.ID))
      featureIds = featureIds.concat(FeaturesGroups.map(o => o.Features.map(o => o. CategoryFeatureId))).flat(2)
    })
```

The two arrays, featureGroupIds and featureIds are now filled with every block ID and every CategoryFeatureId present in my four object.

Now I have to filter the object I call "structure" to remove the block and the features with an ID that is not present in my arrays.

This is my structure, and as you can see is similar.

```
[
      {
        "name": "Display",
        "data": {
          "id": 34566,
          "category_id": 2647
        },
        "features": [
          {
            "name": "Tipo di display",
            "data": {
              "id": 85325,
              "category_id": 2647,
              "feature_id": 9104,
              "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
              "order": 10100140
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Touch screen",
            "data": {
              "id": 85331,
              "category_id": 2647,
              "feature_id": 4963,
              "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
              "order": 10100129
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Dimensioni schermo",
            "data": {
              "id": 158002,
              "category_id": 2647,
              "feature_id": 3544,
              "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
              "order": 100149
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "à di Pixel",
            "data": {
              "id": 85347,
              "category_id": 2647,
              "feature_id": 13246,
              "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
              "order": 100147
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Tipo di vetro",
            "data": {
              "id": 94704,
              "category_id": 2647,
              "feature_id": 7610,
              "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
              "order": 100050
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Altre caratteristiche",
        "data": {
          "id": 34569,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_group_id": 146,
          "name": null,
          "order": 0
        },
        "features": [
          {
            "name": "inside",
            "data": {
              "id": 110410,
              "category_id": 2647,
              "feature_id": 18688,
              "category_feature_group_id": 34569,
              "order": 100000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Here is my function

```
      structure = structure.filter(featureGroup => this.featureGroupIds.includes(featureGroup.data.id));
      structure.map((object) => {
        object.features.filter(feature => this.featureIds.includes(feature.data.feature_id))
      })
```

this.featureIds and this.featureGroupIds are the array with the group IDS and with the feature IDS.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can use a map for that - either an ES6 Map or a temporary plain Object.

Comment: I already do that, it's working. But I want to know if there is a simple and more efficient way

Comment: The most efficient way is when the backend provides you this data exactly in the format you need - so you do not have to do such exercising in the frontend. There is nothing more efficient than that.